Addition theorem for Legendre polynomials in $2$ dimensions
I'm asking this question again, this time through this forum instead of MSE because I think it is more adequate.

We know the addition theorem for Legendre polynomials in spherical coordinates is
$$P_\ell(\cos\gamma)=\dfrac{4\pi}{2\ell +1}\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1,\phi_1)\,\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,\phi_2)$$
where
$$\cos\gamma=\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$$
But what if we were working in polar coordinates? What would be the equivalent in $2$ dimensions? In this case $\cos\gamma$ would simply be $\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$ or $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ depending on the plane you're working in.

Link to the question at mathstack, please?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947173/legendre-addition-theorem-in-2-dimensions
